# php function scope variable always in the end empty

Tags: php, function, scope

I have strange senario i have this simple function that i try to concat simple html string
but the variable that holds that string in the end (after the loop ) is always empty.

```
function buildSelectOptionsASString($elmArray)
{
     global $optionsStr;
    foreach ($elmArray as $Rec)
    {

        if(property_exists($Rec,'id')==true)
        {

            $ElmId = $Rec->id;
            $ElmName = $Rec->name;

            $optionsStr = $optionsStr ."<option value=\"".$ElmId."\">". $ElmName ."</option>\n";  

        }
    }
    echo  $optionsStr;
    return $optionsStr;
}
```

if i print the $ElmId $ElmName and the $optionsStr it prints the contant fine 
BUT when i print the return variable out side the loop its result is empty 
why ?

Comment: is $elmArray an array or an object ? the code says the latter the name says hte former

Comment: You don't need to declare `$optionsStr` as `global`, but you do need to initialise it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare $optionsStr as global. Indeed, if you're returning it as the value of the function, you shouldn't.

Try this:

```
function buildSelectOptionsASString($elmArray)
{
  $optionsStr = "";  // this $optionsStr is local to this function.

  foreach ($elmArray as $Rec)
  {

    if(property_exists($Rec,'id')==true)
    {
        $ElmId = $Rec->id;
        $ElmName = $Rec->name;
        $optionsStr = $optionsStr ."<option value=\"".$ElmId."\">". $ElmName ."</option>\n";  
    }
  }
  echo  $optionsStr;
  return $optionsStr;
}

$elmArray = array();  // set up your array here

$optionsStr = buildSelectOptionsASString($elmArray);  // This is a different $optionsStr

echo $optionsStr;
```